# The Split method in C# and VB.NET

Tags: c#, split

Thanks for someone who might be able to help me further, as I can't find an answer in the www right now. I actually program VB.net, but since this language is now dissolved and not further developed, I want to switch to C#. I am getting on well, because a lot of things are similar. There is only one method where I am stuck.

In vb.net I always liked to use the method:

```
mystring.split(seperator)(part)
```

to get a certain string from a CSV line and work with it. How does this work in C#? I know that I can load everything into an array, but I don't want to do that in this case. A simple split and the number of the element is enough. Can someone help me?

Comment: String.Split() generates an array both in vb.net and c#.  That it doesn't *look* like an array is not relevant.  Use `var column = mystring.Split(separator)[part];` as a direct substitute.

Comment: This isn't about the split method, it's about array access (and in c# you use `[`square brackets`]` to access array items). `Split` will load everything into an array whether you want it to or not. Please read [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-5.0). Downvote for lack of research effort.

Comment: You may find this link helpful in your transition to C#. [VB.NET and C# Quick Reference Comparison](https://sites.harding.edu/fmccown/vbnet_csharp_comparison.html)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the same [split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-5.0) method is what you need? It returns an array which you could store or just access directly. The difference being in C# you use `[index]` instead. So something like this:

```cs
string myFile = File.ReadAllText("myfile.txt");
string firstLine = myFile.Split("\r\n")[0];
```